# How to check status of Wi-Fi adapter through command line?

Tags: macos, wifi, command-line

I read a few stacks on the internet but command line was used only to turn Wi-Fi on or off, but none of them to check the on-off status of Wi-Fi.

Any possible way to check status of Wi-Fi adapter on or off in command line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `ifconfig` *command*, e.g.:

```
$ ifconfig en0 
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether # Removed for Security. 
    inet6 fe80::c44:6ce5:5d57:5b93%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x9 
    inet 192.168.2.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
$
```

You can also filter the output, e.g.:

```
$ ifconfig en0 | awk '/status:/{print $2}'
active
$
```

When not active the output is, e.g:

```
$ ifconfig en0 | awk '/status:/{print $2}'
inactive
$
```

---

If you do not know the *device name* for the **Wi-Fi** *network adapter*, you can use the following examples:

```
$ networksetup -getairportpower $(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk -F: '/Interfaces:/{getline; print $1;}')
Wi-Fi Power (en0): On
$
```

Or:

```
$ ifconfig $(system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk -F: '/Interfaces:/{getline; print $1;}') | awk '/status:/{print $2}'
active
$
```

Comment: @laughing Just note that if you have multiple network interfaces, you'll need to determine which of your network interfaces are your Wifi adapter. For example, on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro, wireless is en1. YMMV. You can use 'ifconfig' on its own to list all your adapters.

Comment: @TraneFrancks so instead of specifying the interface, is there any command line that returns the interface of Wi-Fi adapter? my goal is just to control the Wi-Fi adapter.

Comment: @laughing Just using ifconfig by itself, as stated above, will enable you to determine what the device name is. There is no way to monitor or change settings of a device interface without defining the interface. Between the two answers given here, you should be easily able to determine your interface and then just write a bash script to give you the output you want.

Comment: @laughing, I edited my answer to include examples if one does not know the _device name_ for the **Wi-Fi** _network adapter_.

Comment: I know question didnt ask for it, but can *connected* status be known using CL?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk -F: '/Status:/{print $2}'` with return either `Connected` or `Off`.

Comment: The airport command itself also allows for some wifi control, but its not in the standard shell path

Answer (score 8):

In addition to `ifconfig` and `networksetup`, there's also the `airport` command. It's in an obscure location, so you have to specify the entire path to it (or make an alias, like I have). I find the `-I` (show current status) and `-s` (scan for networks) options most useful (although they're considered "legacy"). Here's an example:

```
$ alias airport=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport
$ airport -I
AirPort: Off
$ # [Switches radio on...]
$ airport -I
     agrCtlRSSI: -49
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -88
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station 
     lastTxRate: 300
        maxRate: 300
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa2-psk
          BSSID: 88:d7:f6:25:c4:37
           SSID: NotMyRealName
            MCS: 15
        channel: 40,-1
```

You can use the `-h` flag to get a list of its options.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, **networksetup** has the command to return the status of airportpower as well.

```
networksetup -getairportpower *specify the interface*
```

For example:

```
networksetup -getairportpower en0
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to simply get the device name is to use the *listallhardwareports* option of **networksetup**. It neatly prints out all the device names for each interface immediately (e.g. it does not need to poll the device status and take a couple seconds to return like **system_profiler** does).

Building off of [user3439894's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/368047/394383), the command to programmatically get the "Wi-Fi" adapter name would be:

```
networksetup -getairportpower $(networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk -F: '/Wi-Fi/{getline; print $2;}')
```

This can be used for any adapter name (not just Wi-Fi), and could easily be paramaterized in a script, e.g.

```
getDeviceNameFromAdapterName() {
    networksetup -listallhardwareports | awk -v adapter="$1" -F : '$0~adapter{getline; print $2;}'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the command I used to check if Wi-Fi enabled on my Mac.

```
networksetup -getinfo Wi-Fi | grep ^Router
```